# Laravel 5.3 - Login Counter - Events & Listeners

Tags: php, laravel

I want to program a Login Counter for my Laravel 5.3 Application.

Later I want to know how many users login for example between 10 & 11 PM.

I created a database with a column called `logins`. Every time when a user logged in my Application I want that a Event count in this column.

I'm struggling at the moment with the Events & Listeners.

In the `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider` i create this in the `$listen` array :

```
protected $listen = [ 
            'App\Events\LoginCount' => [ 
                    'App\Listeners\LoginCount'
            ],
```

My problem at the moment is I try to unterstand how the Events & Listeners collaborate together.

Comment: somewhere in your code you define that event was happened. At this moment will be called the function of listener that is associated with this event as you describe it in service provider

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events

Comment: @Trayer Hi my second me, you can have a look on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events

Comment: @omadonex So, the programming logic is in the event and the listener only "point" on the event and then the magic happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event & Listener concept is quite easy to grasp. Listeners are just observers waiting for event to be fired. They collaborate by exchanging data. When you create an event, you provide all needed data for it, and later you consume it in every attached listener.

In Laravel, to fire an event you have to use `event(new YourEvent($data))`. Let's consider your problem - watching how many user logged between specified hours. Let's create an LoginEvent with a $user and $timestamp property.

```
class LoginEvent {
    public $user;
    public $logged_at;

    public function __construct(User $user, Carbon $logged_at) { ... }
}
```

Such easy class is perfectly enough, all we want is to store data that we will consume later.

So now, in controller or elsewhere you can fire this event. Let's say you have AuthController with Login method:

```
public function login() 
{
   // login implementation...
   $user = // logged user;
   $logged_at = Carbon::now();

   event(new LoginEvent($user, $logged_at));
}
```

And to LoginEvent in EventServiceProvider you attached CountLoginsListener. Suppose something like this:

```
class CountLoginsListener {

    public function handle(LoginEvent $event) 
    {
        if ($this->isHourBetweenSpecifiedPeriod($event)) {
            $login_log = new LoginLog;
            $login_log->user()->associate($event->user);
            $login_log->logged_at = $event->logged_at;
            $login_log->save();
        }
    }
}
```

And you are done.

Comment: Thank you! Great Answer!